# UITableView - Load large UIImages from NSBundle without blocking main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, asynchronous, uiimage

In  UITableViewController, the UI freezes when this method is called: 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

where an image is being loaded into the UITableViewCell.

`cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"filePath"];`

The files are locally stored in the documents folder - this is not a remote call.
I understand that image-loading while the cell is created cusses the main thread to freeze, if this was a remote call i would have uses a-synchronic loading but how would you 
do it for local files?

*images are around 500k.

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: 500K images from bundle to be displayed in table view, in cells? think of making thumbs. That might reduce size 10 times.

Comment: will do and it will improve, but it will still have a small lag when the tableview will reload cells. i want to go 100% free ui - the same responsiveness i would get if i was using ASIHTTPRequest for remote images.

Comment: in question you write you load images from bundle. If you load images not for all table but only those you need now to be displayed, loading will be near immediate provided images have reasonable size. But if you load images from web, your need another approach. Load images in background and instead of not loaded images display placeholder.

Comment: The images are loaded from the document library i.e locally from the device (not NSBundle, but they might as well be) - there are tons of answers about loading remote image , i'm intrested in knowing when a UIImage data is ready so i can display it from a background thread to the ui thread like i would do for remote images. BTW i'm now using thumbs and it now works fine... but the question remains.

Answer (score 0):

For example, make separate thread where you will load images and save reference to them in some `array`. When all images will be prepared (or some part of them), you can `reload` `cell`s that should contains that messages.

In `table view controller` you should check if `image` is already loaded for that `cell` and if it is just take reference and set `cell.imageView.image` with it.

Comment: How would you know that a local file has finished loading?

Comment: When `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"filePath"];` will return reference that will mean that local file is loaded to memory.

Comment: so, you suggest i add an interval to check on it? isn't there targer/action, notification or something i can wait for?

Comment: No, you should just create **separate thread** where you will load that images in circle and when some part of that images was loaded just reload the appropriate cells of table view by calling some method in **main thread**

Comment: Thanks, What exactly do you mean by circle? (while loop?)

Comment: Yes, `while(count < numberOfImages){[arr addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"filePath"]]; count++;}`